# Guest Network not broadcasting

Tags: router, dd-wrt

I have a USR5461 with DD-WRT installed. Seems to work OK. However, the guest network I configured according to instructions does not broadcast at all even though I'm able to ping it.
Is the USR5461 not compatible with VAP? Can the ISP prevent me from configuring a VAP?
Thanx in advance for your input.

Answer (score 1):

Your router along with your installed firmware is fully able to work with VAP for guest networks. It's unusually weird for this to happen since you can ping it, but I'd like to try this to see if this will help or not. I'm curious though. On most routers that I've seen for guest networks the SSID (broadcast name) is set to off by default which means you manually type it in. Swap it to on if this is the case.

First off, you'll want to log into your DDWRT router and then click on the "wireless setting" tab. There should be a button saying "add under Virtual Interfaces," which is where you want to enter your SSID (network broadcast key for your guest network). Click "save" and wait for the router to finish booting back up.

Next, you will want to click on wireless > wireless security tab < and find the Virtual Interface Security section that matches the name of your guest SSID.

Choose the drop down menu and swap it from disabled to secure mode. I would recommend using WPA2-Personal for this as it makes it easier for older devices to connect to.

Select an algorithm for the encryption like TKIP under "WPA Shared Key," type in a password and try to make the password over 12 characters or it may not work correctly. Click "Apply Settings" and wait a full minute or two to apply as well as power cycle it by unplugging it from the wall for 45 seconds. Do not reset it via the control panel as it'll kill the NRAM.

ISPs can block it, but I don't see why they would, and if you can ping it then they can communicate.

Comment: Well, thanks for your input. I really did all the things you mentioned, and I was able to login to my router (192.168.1.1) and VAP (192.168.2.1). But no luck.

Comment: Odd, is there a possibly way to keep creating VAP by going up one by one via the IPs or a way to make a multi cast of it? You're able to log into both, but no internet access? Only one person at a time? etc?

Comment: This site could help, but I'm not sure. It has details on how to setup VAP for multiple users on a guest notwork while having a private one. http://blog.danjoannis.com/?p=1362 but make sure to use your correct broadcast and network IP's and this one as well http://www.dd-wrt.ca/wiki/index.php/Multiple_WLANs

Comment: Well, with all the fiddling I did my router is now semi-bricked. It's still broadcasting the main network but the dd-wrt is corrupted. Can't access the cpe and the router does not respond to a reset. Tried them all 30-30-30 etc. So now I have to look into how to unbrick the router if such a procedure exist when one cannot access the ip adress.